How to fetch Sharepoint users' permissions for specific pages and folders
I'm working as a DE for a Data Science Department that's not a part of our IT Dept. We're making a product that needs to programatically map Sharepoint user access permissions (User A: [folder1, folder2, folder3]) for a specific Sharepoint site, including all subfolders.
The problem is, our IT are not developers - they manage our Microsoft ecosystem from the web console and some parts of their work is outsourced. However, they would be able to give me API access to SP.
I would ask them to give me Sharepoint API access to certain Sharepoint sites, and grant me enough permissions to be able to figure out all permissions (especially if they are inherited and not explicitly set), for each folder. I'm pretty certain they wouldn't know what permissions would be enough to do this.

Most importantly, is there a standard and simple way to get this information?

My initial test would include using Graph API with sufficient level of permissions.

If Graph API is the way to go, what permissions would I need to figure out inherited permissions for all users and folders for a specific SP site?

